# Issue with Connection String with DBcontext in.Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Currently i am working on a .Net core 3.1 App. I am using below code in the startup to Add the Dbcontext.

```
services.AddDbContext<sampleContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

As this is the code first approach i have below code in the Dbcontext

```
public class sampleContext: DbContext
    {
        public sampleContext()
        {

        }
        public sampleContext(DbContextOptions<sampleContext> options) : base(options){ }
        

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DefaultConnection", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process));
            }
        }
}
```

When i am running the API, its working as expected as `optionsBuilder.IsConfigured=true`.

Appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=sampleDb; Integrated Security=true;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "UploadFAUrl": "http://localhost:7071/Api"
}
```

Coming to issue:-

1. When i am running the CLI command `ADD-MIGRATION sampleCon`getting `**Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')**`

Whys is so? As we will be moving to different env, we may need to run this command. Atleast in local, we need to run the command. How to fix this issue? Referred some of the question but non helped. PLease suggest if i am missing anything.

Comment: Do you store your connect strings in appsettings.json, can you show us it?

Comment: Yes its in app settings.json
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=sampleDb; Integrated Security=true;"
  }

Comment: Can you share all your `appsettings.json `?

Comment: Added in the question.

Comment: As i explained, there is no issue i am getting at runtime. While running Migration commands only facing issue. & there we need to select the project where Dbcontext is threre.

Comment: What I want to ask is what do you use for migration, PMC?

Comment: Please make sure that your appsettings.json file is located under the project file and not under other folders.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225195/discussion-between-lokanath-das-and-yinqiu).

Comment: Any help on this issue will be great

Answer (score 1):

The EF Core command line tools, will attempt to locate all required services and configuration, based on your current project. By looking for your `CreateHostBuilder` method, and calling it;

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => ...
```

You shouldn't need to override `OnConfiguring`. But you may need to provide an explicit `--startup-project` [command line parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#target-project-and-startup-project).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple projects?

Mark the project `Set as startup project` which contains `Appsettings.json`.